# Can I rename a Git sub-directory without the URL changing (for its contents)?

Tags: git, url, gitlab, rename, subdirectory

I'm new to Git. I am working on a Git website and I want to rename one of the sub-directories but don't want the URL for its child content to change. This is partly because the broken links would cause issues and partly because the URL would still make sense to the content within if it remained the same.

The sub-directory is currently called 'Advanced Guides' and I want to rename it to 'User Guides' but don't want the URL to change from **xyzi.com.au/Documentation/advanced-guides/...**

Is there a way I can change the sub-directory name without the URL changing?

If we were using a cms it would be possible so I really hope there is a way we can do it on this site. I have been told it's not possible but I find that hard to believe (I'm ever the optimist)!

I've attached a couple of screenshots to show the file structure - one is the view from Finder, the other the view from Terminal:

[This is the sub-directory listing via Finder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9ZVb.png)

[This is the contents of the sub-directory via Terminal, there is a lot of content that would be affected if the URL changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TpeA.png)

[I want this url to remain the same, even after I rename the sub-directory from 'Advanced Guides' to 'User Guides'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K9Xz.png)

What can I try?

Comment: So the question is "how to rename a subdirectory without renaming the subdirectory?" Sorry but no way. Git doesn't provide a mapping from a view to its database.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, assuming your web server supports URL rewriting. However if you are using Git-based hosting (e.g. GitHub pages) then you are probably out of luck, since the host probably does not support it. If you are using IIS or Apache or Nginx then you can probably do this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here, per the comments is, that if you are hosting the remote yourself, you may be able to setup the duplicate names/routes to possibly do what you are looking for. Otherwise, it is likely not possible (on Github, Gitlab, etc.).

However, my answer is, that you should seriously reexamine **why** you want to do this, and likely fix the root cause that is leading you to want to do this, rather than pursue a git or server-based bandaid that will lock in likely bad infrastructure by spreading it even further and longer into your codebase.

Something in your infrastructure has been built with hardcoded links rather than being flexible and/or configurable. Refactoring your infrastructure to support a more flexible approach is much more likely to be worthwhile in the long run, and if time/schedule is of the essence, you can always just do the find/replace to get the hardcoded links changed, but still hardcoded.

---

### Other considerations for an alternate solution

Updating your external URL links will likely break backward compatibility. However, if it does, it is likely you don't have repo interdependencies setup well. For example, using Git SubModules can allow you to tie the commits of one repo to the commits of another repo so that versioning is always inheritly correct.

i.e. If the hardcoded URLs are in an external tool, if you fix those links in its repo while updating the submodule to the commit where the directory name is changing in your main code repo, then the updates to both repos will be sync'd.

Or more simply, if the hardcoded links are in a config file for that tool, just save the config file in the main code repo. This follows the "infrastructure as code" design pattern and best practice. If your external tool is a homegrown tool, it shouldn't be too difficult to change it to accept some kind of a configuration variable in a file, rather than compiling the hardcoded value into the tool.

So, this probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but we've always got to keep learning better techniques for long-term maintainability and scalability, and if you have the time to fix the core issue, this looks like an opportunity to move your project in that direction. As long as this isn't throw-away or one-time development code, that is likely the best option.